# Indexing an array pointed to by a pointer within a Structure

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, type-conversion, structure

Looking at my [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629103/indexing-to-get-access-members-of-a-structure-c-programming) . I got the solution with this set of code

```
const MEMBERS *some_members = (MEMBERS *) GET_MEM();
unsigned value1 = some_members->mem1;
unsigned value2 = *some_members->mem2;
```

Not is worked as I expected. But in the case where sample is an

```
unsigned sample [4] = {2,5,6,1};
```

How do I go about indexing in the arrays if I need to do index to the 3rd character of the array ( i.e sample [3] =1. ) from the structure. Do I make value2 a pointer as well?

Thanks all..

Comment: Not that I understand the question very well, but `sample[3]==1` (indices start from zero).

Comment: @AntonKovalenko thanks...got that corrected.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, yes, make `value2` a pointer.  To wit:

```
const MEMBERS *some_members = (MEMBERS *) GET_MEM();
unsigned value1 = some_members->mem1;
unsigned *value2 = some_members->mem2;

// These are true statements
value2[0] == 2;
value2[1] == 5;
value2[2] == 6;
value2[3] == 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. But it appears that only Value_2[0] ==2. Others does not give the actual value...

Answer (score 1):

Pointers and arrays can be accessed just the same.

For example:

```
int array[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
printf("Third entry in array = %d\n", array[2]);

int *pointer = array;
printf("Third entry in array using pointer = %d\n", pointer[2]);
```

If the pointer is in a structure or not doesn't matter, just use normal field access (e.g. `structure.pointer[2]` or `structpointer->pointer[2]`).